# How to add attribute to child element <a> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, attributes

I am facing issue in add attribute to child element in my scenario. Attribute is appending in parent instead of child tag . Please help me in JavaScript.

I have below code in html

````
  <a href="#">
    <div>dummy</div>
  </a>
</div>

My Javascript is:
-----------------
document.getElementsByClassName('Master')[0].setAttribute('aria-label', 'demo');

Output is:
----------
<div class="Master" aria-label="demo">
  <a href="#">
    <div>dummy</div>
  </a>
</div>

Expected output will be:
-------------------------
<div class="Master">
  <a href="#" aria-label="demo">
    <div>dummy</div>
  </a>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can directly target the specific element (*a*) using [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) that allows CSS like selector:

```js
document.querySelector('.Master a').setAttribute('aria-label', 'demo');

console.log(document.querySelector('.Master a'));
```

```html
<div class="Master" aria-label="demo">
  <a href="#">
    <div>dummy</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If you have multiple elements then use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.Master a').forEach(function(el){
  el.setAttribute('aria-label', 'demo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mamun.. Exact solution you found for me !

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the specific anchor tag.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Master')[0].getElementsByTagName('A')[0].setAttribute('aria-label', 'demo');
```

Suggest using a class directly in the anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar Shahi!!. Brilliant solution am getting.